# How to add new ciphersuites to Bouncycastle TLS or JCE?

Tags: cryptography, bouncycastle, jce

I have a challenging question. How can I define new ciphersuites such as an encryption scheme A with AES256 (Hybrid) in combination with a Signature scheme B in order to operate it with Bouncycastle TLS 1.3 or TLS 1.2. 
I do not want to use predefined ones from bouncycastle.
What are the steps towards doing this? Is there a fast way?
The same also for JCE?

Many thanks for your great help.

Comment: You need to learn programming to add new ciphersuites not already implemented by standard software. You also should learn cryptography.

Comment: I design cryptographic primitives. However, the bouncycastle library has not so much documentation. Using standard TLS is not a problem. However, how to use other primitives as in my question above?

Comment: I'd try the Bouncy Castle mailing list, but personally I think you should look up the existing cipher suites and work backward from that.